# Undestanding how to use JPA to abstract the ORM

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am working on a Java project for the university and I am trying to learn about framework, technologies and best practices for creating a well structured software that follows software engineering principles. I decided to use `Spring (Spring-data-jpa)`, and `Hibernate` for the standalone software and now I am  having some trouble in understanding how to use the Java Persistence Api to create an abstraction layer above the Hibernate implementation provider. What I am trying to figure out is in which part (configuration file or java class) I can switch from an ORM tool to another one. I saw that I have to use the persistence.xml file to specify the persistence unit and persistence context and also the DB parameters, but it's not clear how the EntityManager bind itself with the underlying ORM tool and in which properties this bind is set. Is the "provider" properties inside persistence.xml file that create this binding? Any link/references/examples or guide will be appreciated, thanks in advance and excuse me for my english ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each persistence unit in he persistence.xml file is associated to a provider. For example, with Hibernate:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

If you want to use another provider, you'll specify another value for this element.

Note that this is usually unnecessary, because you typically use only one provider in an application. If a single provider is available in the classpath, JPA will use that one. So switching from Hibernate to EclipseLink for example just consists in having the EclipseLink jars in the classpath rather than the Hibernate jars.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate works on the JPA API so you don't have to explicitly configure JPA if you are using hibernate. The ORM integration happens in the DAO "Data Access Object" layer of your application.

Comment: So if i want to switch from Hibernate to another ORM what does i have to change in the project?